# Showing and hiding a list of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I am trying to make a page to where a service can be clicked on and then its description will show. I kind of have it figured out, but at the same time, it is far from where I want it.

Right now, I just have a services div for all of them and then a service_description div for the descriptions. Any service I click on shows all of the particular service descriptions. I want the service description to show up for only that service clicked on.

I am using a toggle approach. I'm not sure if that is the best option. Upon page load, everything is showing, which I do not want the descriptions showing unless clicked on.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".service").click(function(){
        $(".service_description").toggle(1000);
    });
});
</script>

<div class="service_list">
    <button class="service">Floors</button>
        <div class="service_description">dsggafgg</div>
    <div class="service">Roofs</div>
        <div class="service_description">dsggafgg</div>
    <div class="service">Siding</div>
        <div class="service_description">dsggafgg</div>
    <div class="service">Paint</div>
        <div class="service_description">dsggafgg</div>
    <div class="service">Kitchen Remodels</div>
        <div class="service_description">dsggafgg</div>
</div>
```

I created a fiddle, but I am unsure of how to add in the Jquery library, it has changed since the last time I used it.

https://jsfiddle.net/huj2fkra/#&togetherjs=P1EtO37uUE

How can I single each service? I really don't want to make a toggle script with a bunch of different div's because if one service is selected, I want that description to go away if I click on another service.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to toggle description for the service which clicked? which is next to that div. if so this should work $(this).next(".service_description").toggle(1000);

Comment: Say you click on the service 'Roofs'. Say 'Roofs' description was "We will make your roof look perfect!". I want that to come up. Then if someone clicks on siding, I want the roof description to go away and then the siding one to come up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would wrap each service in a `div` like so:

```
<div class="service-wrapper">
  <div class="service-title">Floors</div>
  <div class="service-description">...</div>
</div>
<div class="service-wrapper">
  <div class="service-title">Roofs</div>
  <div class="service-description">...</div>
</div>
<div class="service-wrapper">
  <div class="service-title">Siding</div>
  <div class="service-description">...</div>
</div>
<div class="service-wrapper">
  <div class="service-title">Paint</div>
  <div class="service-description">...</div>
</div>
<div class="service-wrapper">
  <div class="service-title">Kitchen Remodels</div>
  <div class="service-description">...</div>
</div>
```

Then, you could do something like this (https://jsfiddle.net/3ofLfa4t/):

```
$('.service-wrapper').click(function() {
  var thisDescription = $('.service-description', $(this));

  // Hide all other descriptions
  $('.service-description').not(thisDescription).hide();

  // Toggle (show or hide) this description
  thisDescription.toggle();
});
```

The `$('.service-description', $(this))` call just tells jQuery to lookup only the `.service-description` elements inside the wrapper that was clicked, ignoring those that are outside the wrapper.

Comment: So I would have multiple service-wrapper, service-title, and service-description divs? or are you saying to have one service-wrapper div with multiple service-title/description divs? 

Sorry just a bit confused on exactly what you mean.

Comment: You would want a `service-wrapper` for each service if you do it this way. I updated my answer to include your data as an example.

Comment: This is definitely closer to what I am looking for. All of the descriptions still show on page load. I want them hidden.

Then let's say the floor service was clicked on and the description shows, if I click floors again, I want the description to go away.

How can I tackle those issues?

Comment: You can use css for that. `.service-description { display: none; }`

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't think that would work because of the javascript already having hide implemented. I am really new to Javascript, so sorry for my lack of knowledge!! Any idea about clicking the same service to make the description go away? Right now if I click on it again, it just goes away and pops up again. You can see what I mean from the top part, here : http://realtorcatch.com/service

Comment: I updated the answer so it toggles instead of always just shows the element you want

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! Quick random question, how did you get the jquery library to load in jsfiddle? Before I was able to select it from a drop down on the left.

Comment: Just had the issue myself :)- It's in the settings icon inside the javascript panel now.

Comment: Wow, so easy. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use slideUp, slideDown:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".service_list .service_description").hide();
    $(".service").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".service_description").siblings('.service_description').slideUp(1000);
        if ($(this).next(".service_description").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next(".service_description").slideUp(1000); 
        }else{
            $(this).next(".service_description").slideDown(1000);   
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$(".service").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".service_description").toggle(1000);
});
```

Should do the trick